# Find maximum value in python dataframe combining several rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like following(I have sorted it according to item column already). For example, item 1- 10,11-20,...(every 10 items) are in the same category, I want to find the item in each category that have the highest score and return it.

What is the most efficient way to do that?

```
    item    score
1   1   10
3   4   1
4   6   6
39  11  2
8   12  1
9   13  1
10  15  24
11  17  9
12  18  12
13  20  7
14  22  1
59  25  3
18  28  3
19  29  2
22  34  2
23  37  1
24  38  3
25  39  2
26  40  2
27  42  3
29  45  1
31  48  1
32  53  4
33  58  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your dataframe is stored in df

```
g = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.item, np.arange(1, df.item.max(), 10), right=False)
```

)

get the max values from each category

```
max_score_ids = g.score.agg('idxmax')
```

this gives you the ids of the rows that contain the max score in each category

```
item
[1, 11)      1
[11, 21)    10
[21, 31)    59
[31, 41)    24
[41, 51)    27
```

then get the items associated with these ids

```
df.loc[max_score_ids].item

1      1
10    15
59    25
24    38
27    42
```